# Use Hibernate-search in multiple database instances

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am working in a Hibernate-search application, currently I have been indexing a postgres database and after I created some Lucene queries and as far everything is working fine.

I have some concerns about if it is possible to use Hibernate-search with multiple instances (where all instance have the same db structure). That is because I want to split the information in several instances (not only local) and avoid to store all data in a single one.

1. What is the best approach to do this?
2. Can I use Hibernate-search to do this?

I would think there is a way to have several instances in a same Lucene Index, so I could query that index to get and retrieve information no matter where is the data coming from. But I would think the indexation process should be different as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the best approach would be using [Hibernate Search 6](http://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) and its Elasticsearch integration. The idea is that instead of indexing locally, Hibernate Search delegates to a cluster of Elasticsearch nodes (which can be only one node if that's what you want). Clustering will be completely transparent to your application.

If you're currently on Hibernate Search 5, upgrading to 6 will require some work, since the artifact IDs, internal architecture and APIs changed. Hibernate Search 6 is also currently in Beta, so the APIs are reasonably stable but the migration guide is not ready yet, for example. I'd recommend having a look at the [getting started guide for Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started) before you make the jump.

If you want to stay on Search 5, or if you want to avoid Elasticsearch for some reason, then your only remaining option is to use Search 5's "clustering" backends relying on JMS or JGroups. However, these architectures are complex to set up, which is the very reason we gave up on them in Search 6 (at least for now) and focused on the Elasticsearch integration. See [here for JMS](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture-jms) and [here for JGroups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture-jgroups).